# Python - use dictionary of **kwargs including variables before assignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a custom function that takes a bunch of arguments, called multiple times with different configurations of said arguments. For cleanliness & ease of use I would like to define a dicts of arguments before all the function calls that are then passed to each call as `**kwargs`:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, arg3, opt_arg4=x, opt_arg5=y, opt_arg6=z):
    do_something

dict1 = {'arg1': 'foo', 'arg2': 'bar', 'arg3': 'baz', 'opt_arg4': 42}
dict2 = {'arg1': 'Ni', 'arg2': 'Peng', 'arg3': 'Neee-Wom', 'opt_arg5': 'yellow'}
dict3 = {'arg1': 'Ni', 'arg2': 'bar', 'arg3': 'Ekke ekke', 'opt_arg6': name}

func(**dict1)
func(**dict2)
func(**dict3)
```

My problem arises if I want some of the arguments in the dictionaries to be variables that haven't been defined yet. So they'd be referenced before assignment except just as placeholders that would be defined later before actually being used. For instance, `dict3` above contains `'opt_arg6': name` where `name` is meant to be a variable, and it would be used like this:

```
knightlist = ['Lancelot', 'Galahad', 'Robin']
for name in knightlist:
    func(**dict3)
```

Is there some way to do this or achieve a similar result?

**Edit:**
Slightly more detail, excerpted from the actual code:

```
i = 1
for c in c_list: # Where c_list has been read in from input
    compile_func(somedict[c], c, i, {'model': f'_{c}', 'optparm': '_i'}, log=logfile, subdir=c)
# Where somedict and logfile have previously been defined
```

I would like to be able to replace this with:

```
c_args = {'arg1': somedict[c], 'arg2': c, 'arg3': i, 'arg4': {'model': f'_{c}', 'optparm': '_i'}, 'log': logfile, 'subdir': c}
# With the actual arg names as keys of course

Bunch_of_other_code()

i=1
for c in c_list:
    compile_func(**c_args)
```

Or something similarly separable. Hope that's clearer!

**Edit 2:** Trying to get at the more fundamental problem:
For a function with lots of arguments, some of which are variables or modifications of variables, what ways are there to pass the arguments that are relatively neat, readable, and easily modified? Especially if called multiple times with different sets of arguments that I'd like to be able to configure in the same place in the code?

Comment: What's the problem do: `dict3['opt_arg6'] = name` just before `func(**dict3)`?

Comment: @stovfl see edits and discussion below - the actual code involves rather more variables or modifications thereof, so while that would work, it would get quite messy, which defeats what I'm trying to achieve in the first place (organizing it more neatly than just entering all the args in each function call).

Answer (score 2):

Mix explicit keyword arguments with unpacking. Remove `'opt_arg6'` from `dict3`, and just do:

```
for name in knightlist:
    func(opt_arg6=name, **dict3)
```

Aside from that, the closest to what you're trying to do would be to define a function that generates the `dict` you want, and call it when you need the `dict`. This will not improve performance at all (as the `dict` is still regenerated each time), but it might conceivably simplify your calling code a bit. Example to match your second code example would replace the definition of `c_args` with:

```
def make_c_args(c, i):
    return {'arg1': somedict[c], 'arg2': c, 'arg3': i, 'arg4': {'model': f'_{c}', 'optparm': '_i'}, 'log': logfile, 'subdir': c}


Bunch_of_other_code()

i=1
for c in c_list:
    compile_func(**make_c_args(c, i))
```

You could avoid accepting and passing `c` and `i` if the function is in the same scope and can access `c` and `i` from its own outer scope.

A similar approach would be to write a wrapper for your `compile_func` that does the necessary `c` work, expanding from explicit `c` passed to all the associated explicit keyword arguments to `compile_func`. In all cases, you really have to do all the same work; it's not possible to have a `dict` with lazily evaluated values the way you seem to want without deferring creation of the `dict` until the lazy values are in fact available eagerly.

Comment: This would work, but (the example code being of course simplified) in some cases I'd like multiple arguments to be variables or the same variable, enough that mixing them as you suggest would somewhat defeat the purpose of the unpacking in the first place (namely, readability and ease of modification), as it would be only marginally better than just specifying the arguments in the function call. Is there a way to do it that would still allow passing the args more elegantly/concisely?

Comment: @TYLim: I'd need a more complete example to suggest anything; you're describing what could be a very complex scenario with no better solutions, but it could have shortcuts that depend *entirely* on the details you omitted. Often cases like this are a bit of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Comment: Added some details from the actual code above, hopefully makes it a bit clearer... I know it's getting at a more fundamental architectural problem that I've [previously asked about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153371/best-way-to-create-python-function-with-multiple-options), [not always successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616330/creating-subclasses-vs-passing-multiple-arguments-to-specify-variants-of-a-func)...

Comment: @TYLim: Yeah, your problem doesn't have any magic solutions. You have to do the work, every time; all you can do is hide it from the call site by making helper functions to do the work you don't want to do "somewhere else".

Comment: Got it... that's not entirely unexpected. As a relative novice I am always discovering more new 'magic solutions' and so always wonder if there's something I'm missing, but 'no simple solution' is a helpful answer too. Thanks for understanding!